# C++ Unknown type name even though type is defined through headers

Tags: c++

This is driving me insane, I have a class called Model, a class called View, and a header file for something GameCommand. I've included the right header guards and everything as far as I can tell but I keep getting an unknown type name error

Model.h

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

class Model
{
public:
    Model(); //default constructor
};

#endif
```

Model.cpp

```
#include "Model.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Model::Model() //default constructor
{
whatever
}
```

View.h

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

class View
{
public:
    View(); 
};

#endif
```

View.cpp

```
#include "View.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

View::View()
{ whatever
}
```

GameCommand.h

```
#ifndef GAMECOMMAND_H
#define GAMECOMMAND_H
#include "Model.h"
#include "View.h"

void DoGoCommand(Model&, View&);
```

```
error: unknown type name 'Model'
void DoGoCommand(Model&, View&);
                 ^
error: unknown type name 'View'
void DoGoCommand(Model&, View&);
                         ^
```

I feel like I've tried everything, is there something I am just not seeing here?

Comment: Is those errors you show the *full* and *complete* copy-pasted output you get when building?

Comment: There's multiple functions within GameCommand that use Model and View and the only errors I am getting are all unknown type name 'Model' or unknown type name 'View' erros for each function that uses them

Comment: Do either of `Model.h` or `View.h` include each other?

Comment: You aren't probably showing the whole code.  At least I can't reproduce with what you gave.

Comment: In `GameCommand.h` you could probably use  forward declarations for `Model` and `View` and not include the headers.

Comment: Model.h does include View.h, this a small part of a very large code so I'm not sure how much more to include since this seems to be my only error when I try to compile

Comment: Wait -- Are these really *compiler* errors, or errors from some tool that analyzes the source code, like Intellisense or similar?

Comment: That means you have a circular include dependency. One usually solves it by *forward declarations* as mentioned.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: "this a small part of a very large code so I'm not sure how much more to include" try the opposite: include as little as possible, but make sure you can reproduce the error with the small example

Comment: @RaunaqZamal Well if `Model.h` includes `View.h`, then your initial post of the code is misleading.  That's why my previous comment was given concerning a compiler error as opposed to an error generated by a tool that analyzes the source code.

Comment: What is this `whatever`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to forward declare the classes.

class Model;

class View;

in your GameCommand.h